# Limiting distribution $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/n$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

If $X_1, . . ., X_n$ is a random sample with distribution $Geo(\theta)$. Find the limiting distribution for $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/n$

I know the idea is to solve for $lim_{n\to\infty}P(Y_n\le y)$ but end up with a 0 instead of a distribution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), or using the [PDF of a function of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables)

Comment: @Zen Central limit theorem relates to a standardized mean (or standardized sum). The limiting distribution of the unstandardized sample *mean* is not Gaussian.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Strong Law of Large Numbers?

Comment: @Glen_b: you're saying that $Y_n$ does not have approximately, for large $n$, a normal distribution with mean $1/\theta$ and variance $(1-\theta)/(\theta^2\cdot n)$?

Comment: There's a difference between looking at the limiting distribution of $({Y_n-\mu_Y})/(\sigma_Y/\sqrt{n})$ (which is standard normal) and the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ itself. If the question is about the limiting distribution of $Y_n$ then in the limit the cdf of that converges to $_{x\ge\mu_Y}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Glen! When I mentioned the CLT, I didn't mean that the limiting distribution was normal, as per my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

The Central Limit Theorem tells you that, for large $n$, the distribution of $Y_n$ is approximately
$$
  \mathrm{N}\left(\frac{1}{\theta}, \frac{1-\theta}{\theta^2\cdot n}\right).
$$
Hence, as $n\to\infty$, the ditribution of $Y_n$ becomes a degenerate distribution at $1/\theta$:
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\{Y_n\leq y\} = I_{[1/\theta,\infty)}(y). 
$$